Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>
I'm getting a strange error when I run a Typescript build.
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(node: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>, options?: ShallowRendererProps | undefined): ShallowWrapper<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(node: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>, options?: ShallowRendererProps | undefined): ShallowWrapper<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(node: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>, options?: ShallowRendererProps | undefined): ShallowWrapper<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.

return shallow(<EmptyViewComponent {...props} />)

For the following code (and any others that seem to use ShallowWrapper.
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme'

const renderComponent = (props: React.ComponentProps<typeof EmptyViewComponent>): ShallowWrapper => {
    return shallow(<EmptyViewComponent {...props} />)
}

where EmptyViewComponent is just a JSX component.
But I haven't seemed to change anything related to these tests, so perhaps it could something about my git workspace that's causing this.
I'm using 3.11.0 version of enzyme which has ShallowWrapper and shallow.
